# Problem-Heavy References in Linear/Integer/etc. Programming and Operations Research

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I am reaching out for problem-heavy references in Linear / Integer / Mixed-Integer (MIP) / Non-Linear / Network Programming and Operations Research (and Linear Algebra as it pertains to the programming and OR subjects).

I find it easier to learn with problems I can carry around and do, but I tend to complete all my coursework early in the semester and need more material to study from to compensate the free time. Any assistance in this would be genuinely appreciated!

Comment: Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe has a lot of great, challenging problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend *Model Building in Mathematical Programming* by H. Paul Williams. Formulations, SAS code, and output for all 29 examples are included in the SAS documentation [here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/ormpex/15.2/titlepage.htm).

Comment: Wow, this is even better than if someone compiled [all of these posts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A65277+linear+programming) into a book - and that's a high bar.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Disclaimer: I wrote that SAS documentation. 

Comment: I appreciate both of these responses, this gives a lot of material to work with, thank you both!!!

Answer (score 0):

Upon asking my Professors, and looking around online myself, I have a semi-comprehensive list of resources that could work well for self-studying OR and Linear/Non-Linear/etc. Programming:

- [Foundations of Operations Research Practice exercises: Linear Programming](https://amaldi.faculty.polimi.it/SlidesFOR-19-20/FOR-exercises-19-20/LP_practice_solutions-18-19.pdf) by M. Ciavotta (2019)

  - Contains thirteen pages of nine exercises and solutions that can serve as a supplement/review
- [Linear Programming Exercises by Lieven Vandenberghe](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/ee236a/homework/problems.pdf) ($2015$; University of California)

  - Contains $98$ exercises that cover almost all intro/advanced levels of Linear Programming
- [Operations Research - Sample Homework Assignments](http://user.engineering.uiowa.edu/%7Edbricker/OR_Sample_HW/HW_F97.pdf) by Dennis Bricker ($1997$; University of Iowa)

  - Contains $87$ pages of OR models and various scenarios.
- [Problems and exercises in Operations Research](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Eliberti/teaching/dix/inf572-09/exercises-nosol.pdf) by Leo Liberti ($2007$; École Polytechnique)

  - Thirty-three pages of various Linear/Network/Integer problems
- [Operations Research Models and Methods](https://utw11041.utweb.utexas.edu/ORMM/frontpage/contents/text.html) (Website)